# Unable to connect pyqtSignal with pyQtSlot - PyQt5 and Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

Trying to use QThread and PyQt5's slots/signals to process multiple files in backgrounds threads.

I'm using Python 3.5.2 with PyQt5.8.2.  PyCharm 2017.1 gives me warnings for:

- both the `# FAILS HERE` lines `Unresolved attribute reference` for the `connect` part of `w.done.connect(..)`
- and `Cannot find reference 'connect' in 'function'` for the `thread.started.connect(...)`.

When I try and run outside of PyCharm I get `TypeError: decorated slot has no signature compatible with Worker.done[]`.
When looking at tab complete in PyCharm, there is no `connect()` or `disconnect()` methods shown, but `emit()` does.
All tutorials and questions here on SO say the below should work.

The Simplified code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

class MyApp(QMainWindow, myUiMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init()
        self.setupUI(self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def update_this(self):
        <update things>

    def doMyStuff(self):
        <get a file_list>
        for f in file_list:
            w = Worker(f)
            thread = QThread()
            w.moveToThread(thread)
            w.done.connect(self.update_this)       # FAILS HERE
            thread.started.connect(w.process)      # FAILS HERE
            thread.start()

class Worker(QObject):
    done = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent=None)
        self.f = file_path

    @pyqtSlot()
    def process(self):
        <do stuff>
        self.done.emit()
```

update:  I was able to get past this issue finally by uninstalling pyqt5 and reinstalling from here (anaconda.org/bpentz/pyqt5). I have no idea how this solved the issue, but it did. However, this code does not work, it closes the QThread() almost immediately. I updated the following relevant code (below) and now I get a python crash with no Traceback either in terminal or PyCharm (oddly, this works just fine in debugger).  The goal is to loop through files and process them in multiple QThreads(), updating a progress bar (update_this) and then alert user when all files processed.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

        class MyApp(QMainWindow, myUiMainWindow):

            def __init__(self):
                super(self.__class__, self).__init()
                self.setupUI(self)
                self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.doMyStuff)

            @pyqtSlot()
            def thread_complete(self):
                self.num_completed += 1
                if self.num_completed == len(self.file_list):
                    <reset things>

            def doMyStuff(self):
            <get a self.file_list>
            self.num_completed = 0
            self.threads = []
            for f in self.file_list:
                w = Worker(f)
                self.threads.append(QThread())
                w.moveToThread(threads[-1])       
                self.threads[-1].started.connect(w.process)  
                self.threads[-1].finished.connect(self.thread_complete)    
                self.threads[-1].start()

        class Worker(QObject):
            def __init__(self, file_path):
                super(Worker, self).__init__(parent=None)
                self.f = file_path

            @pyqtSlot()
            def process(self):
                <do stuff with self.f>
```

additional update:  As mentioned, the issue was not keeping the worker in memory.  Once this was done, the threading scenario worked. However, also as mentioned, using QThread() did not achieve the idea of multiprocessing for efficiency that I was looking for and thought QThreading might achieve, and bogged things down even worse than just processing the files serially in a single QThread().  Attempts at using mutliprocessing lead to other issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983105/pyqt5-and-multiprocessing-multiple-processes-create-multiple-windows-incorrect).

Working QThread() code (though slow!):

```
def doMyStuff(self):
    <get a self.file_list>
    self.num_completed = 0
    self.threads = []
    self.workers = []
    for f in self.file_list:
        w = Worker(f)
        w.done.connect(self.update_this)
        thread = QThread()
        w.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.started.connect(w.process)
        thread.finished.connect(self.thread_complete)
        self.threads.append(thread)
        self.workers.append(worker)
```

Comment: The constructor of the class MyApp?

Comment: change `@pyqtSlot(object)` to `@pyqtSlot()`

Comment: @eyllanesc - thank you.  I had changed that earlier and it did not work.  I was able to get past this issue by uninstalling pyqt5 and reinstalling from here (https://anaconda.org/bpentz/pyqt5).  I have no idea how this solved the issue, but it did.  However, this code does not work, it closes the QThread() almost immediately.  I've updated the code to the edit above and the new problem.

Comment: show complete code please.

Comment: The constructor of the class `MyApp`?

Comment: updated to include constructor

Comment: @launchpadmcquack you need to keep references to the workers or else they get deleted when `doMyStuff` returns (before your threads get a chance to run). Add them to a list like you are doing with the threads.

Comment: @user3419537 - thank you, that did fix it.  I thought by moving the worker to the thread and keeping the threads in self that it would take care of it.  Oddly though, by doing this, it ran much slower than writing blocking code that processes the files serially within the main.  Will update OP to reflect this shortly.

Comment: @launchpadmcquack python's GIL stops PyQt from achieving true parallelism. Only one thread can run at at time, so you have the overhead from creating the threads and context - switching between them. Python threads are mostly used for keeping the UI responsive

Comment: @user3419537 -thx for the info.  is it possible to use multiprocessing then in the background?  I thought I had tried that and it all went wonky.  Will try using mp here again now that I understand QThread().

Comment: Yes, with multiprocessing you can get true parallel execution

Comment: attempted to do multiprocessing again, and ran into the wonky.  Will update the OP to show what I added and what I found.

Comment: @launchpadmcquack you should create a new question for the problems you're having now as this is no longer related to the original problem

Answer (score -2):

you should might subclass QThread directly

```
class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()
        self.setTerminationEnabled(True)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        pass
        #do work here
```

you can connect to this object a slot, the threads emits "finished"

```
 myworker = WorkerThread(data)
 myworker.finished.connect(doWhatYouWant)
```