# PyQt5 and multiprocessing - multiple processes create multiple windows incorrectly

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, multiprocess

Trying to implement multiprocessing within a PyQt5 GUI framework to process multiple files in a parallel process, preferably in a QThread() background. Running the code below seems to create the multiple processes but has additional issue that multiple GUI windows appear and everything seems locked out at that point.

```
import multiprocess as mp
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

class MyApp(QMainWindow, myUiMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init()
        self.setupUI(self) 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.doMyStuff)

    def consumer(self, inQ, outQ):
        val = inQ.get()
        ret = self.process_single(val)
        outQ.put(ret)

    def process_single(self, f):
        <process each file f>
        <update progress bar>
        return f

    def doMyStuff(self):
        <get file_list from GUI Widget>
        n_w = len(file_list) if len(file_list) < 5 else 5
        inQ = mp.Queue()
        outQ = mp.Queue()

        workers = [mp.Process(target=consumer, args=(inQ, outQ) for i in range(n_w)]
        [w.start() for w in workers]
        [inQ.put(f) for f in file_list]
        [inQ.put(None) for i in range(n_w)]

        completed_files = []
        while len(completed_files) != len(file_list):
            completed_files.append(outQ.get())

        [w.join() for w in workers]
```

Comment: `[w.start() for w in workers]` That's a funny way to perform actions! Less original but you could do in one line `for w in workers: w.start()`.

Answer (score 0):

Guess what...

implement the following to build the GUI only once:

```py
    import multiprocess as mp
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    from QtWidgets import QMainWindow

    ... snippet ... your script code ...

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MyApp()
        window.setGeometry(300, 100, 600, 600)   # adjustable (left,top,width,height)
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

... you probably figured this one out by now ;p